# Visual Studio restoration of Nuget packages through TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, nuget

Today I ran in to a problem that took me a little while to figure out because of my apparent misunderstanding of how the [Enable NuGet Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) worked within source controlled projects in TFS. So to start out with let me explain the issues that I have spent the last week or so troubleshooting.

On our TFS server, I created a build definition for continuous integration. When the source code is checked-in, the build server begins compiling the source and then fails due to not being able to fetch NuGet packages. I thought initially that it was due to `Enable NuGet Package Restore` being disabled, so I switched it on at the solution level and re-committed my code. The builds continued to fail. Without having admin access to the Virtualized Instance of the build server, and the admin being swamped lately I let moved on and decided I'd deal with it in a couple of weeks when my Sprint and his Sprint lightens up. Getting the build server up and running is not a must at the moment. I did however remove my local mapping to the branch in TFS, delete the local directory, re-map the source code and perform a fresh get and re-compiled the source without any problems. The NuGet packages downloaded just fine.

Today however we had a new-hire join the team. He pulled a fresh copy from TFS and encountered some [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) ([for transforming our WPF App Configs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx)) NuGet failures. We spent a good chunk of time today trying to figure out why his wasn't pulling down the files properly. After a little while, I right clicked on his solution and noticed that the `Enable NuGet package Restore` option was available. Even though on my solution, I had enabled it, his solution did not have it set up. I enabled it and immediately his solution compiled without error.

So now down to the primary question, if I enable the solution to restore packages why do I have to re-enable it on another box? I was under the assumption that by making sure `Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build` option is enabled in settings on all of the boxes, Visual Studio would automatically download the NuGet packages missing from my TFS source code. This confuses me and I would appreciate some clarity on how NuGet should work (and be restored) when packages are used in a project stored in TFS. We are not including any of the packages with our TFS check-ins because I though this feature was supposed to automatically work for the project.

Lastly, I am wondering if this is why my build server is failing to run my build definition. I am getting the NuGet errors and am not sure how to tell the build definition to download the NuGet packages. Is this something I need to do by modifying the build template, adding a sequence to download NuGet packages prior to running MSBuild or something?

Thanks in advance.

*Edit 1* I would like to also mention that the `NuGet .targets` file is included in the TFS branch as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Package Restore Consent and for the IDE you need to do it per user. There is a way to override per machine, but its easier per user.

For servers you can use the EnableNuGetPackageRestore environment variable with a value of 'true'

Find out more on: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore

Comment: Thanks, I will do some research on EnableNuGetPackageRestore and see if that fixes it and report back.